# Android - dbclient for SCP

Tags: android, ssh

I'm trying to get scp working from phone to computer.

It works from computer to phone.

But from phone to computer I got:

```
/usr/bin/dbclient: No such file or directory
```

How can I get dbclient on Android?

I looked at CyanogenMod's sources, but it seems to have the same issue and to not provide a dbclient binary.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go for me: compiling from source with Android NDK and patches from: http://dan.drown.org/android/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at the [Connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) source-code - it does not do scp but does provide SSH shell access, maybe the answer is somewhere in there.

Also the dumload project seems to contain scp client code; get it with:

```
git clone http://git.joshuawise.com/dumload.git/
```

Comment: I did. But I don't want to recode a SCPClient, and it does not provide a scp/dbclient binary.

Comment: I am not aware of any stock or custom ROM that comes with a built-in scp binary. Not saying it might not exist though, or that one cannot build a native library that could be installed with your app.

Answer (score 0):

scp from mobile to PC apk is available in the below link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perdeas.droidscp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wZXJkZWFzLmRyb2lkc2NwIl0.

below APIs could be useful.

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

Comment: Sorry but I want to cross-compile SCP, not use an APK